# Computing distance matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I want to find out how many distance calculations are necessary to compute the `n × n` distance matrix for `n` points?
Is there something like a basic rule using only variables?

Comment: Do you want to do better than $O(n^2)$?

Comment: Yes, if possible.

Comment: @user1170330 : in what kind of space do the points live?